# overloading DB field type from Text to SS_DateTime

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm currently working on encrypting some DB fields using [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/). The way I chose to do this was to encrypt the specific fields on `MyObject->setField()` and decrypt on `MyObject->getField`, like the following:

```
public function getField($field)
{
    $val = parent::getField($field);

    if (in_array($field, static::$fieldsToEncrypt)) {
        $key = $this->getEncryptionKey();
        try {
            $newVal = Crypto::decrypt($val, $key);
            $val = $newVal;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    return $val;
}

public function setField($fieldName, $val)
{
    if (in_array($fieldName, static::$fieldsToEncrypt)) {
        $key = $this->getEncryptionKey();
        $val = Crypto::encrypt($val, $key);
    }

    return parent::setField($fieldName, $val);
}
```

In order for the encryption to work, I had to change my field types to `Text`, which was fine for all the `Varchar` fields. Now I have a field that is of time `DateTime` that also needs encrypting, well, it is actually an extension of `SS_DateTime`, but this extension is shared by other fields on other objects too so I can't/shouldn't(?) do it at the DBType level.

Since this is on an existing site, I'd rather not have to rewrite every mention of this field to create a new `SS_DateTime` from a string.

How would I be able to overload the field time "back" to `DateTime` after decrypting it?

Thanks

Comment: I would try `DBField::create_field('DateTime', $val)` on the date fields you want to convert. It might be good to store the data type in the `$fieldsToEncrypt` array to check in the `getField` function and automatically convert the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer was simpler than I expected. Simply adding casting to the object seemed to do the job. Eg:

```
private static $db = array(
    'DOB' => 'Text' // should be DateTime
);

private static $casting = array(
    'DOB' => 'DateTime'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your output using `DBField::create_field()`, as per Silverstripe's documentation https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/data_types_and_casting/#casting

Example:

```
private static $db = array(
    'Date' => 'Text' // Encrypted value
);

public function getField($field)
{
    $val = parent::getField($field);

    if (in_array($field, static::$fieldsToEncrypt)) {
        $key = $this->getEncryptionKey();
        try {
            $newVal = Crypto::decrypt($val, $key);
            $val = $newVal;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    return $val;
}

public function getDate()
{
    // Cast it to DateTime
    return DBField::create_field('DateTime', $this->getField('Date'));
}
```